# Ho to test a create function in Django?

Tags: django, testing

```
# my .views
def post_create_view(request):
    form = PostModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
        form = PostModelForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'form.html', context)
```

```
# my .urls
path('create/', post_create_view, name='create')
```

```
# my .test

class TestViews(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.create_url = reverse('posts:create')
        self.user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
        self.post1 = Post.objects.create(user=self.user, title='testpost', content='fgh')
        self.query = Post.objects.all()

    def test_blog_create_POST(self):
# this is where the error surely is
        response = self.client.post(self.create_url, {'title': 'testpost2', 'content': 'asd'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
# this is where the test fail
        self.assertEqual(self.query.last().title, "testpost2")
```

'testpost2' doesn't get created but my form works fine. How can I simulate the inputs in my testcase?
self.create_url redirect to the correct url, the one with the form in the template, such form works great, but when I write the response in my test the dictionary I pass as second arguments seems not to go through.

Answer (score 0):

In case of invalid form it's just re-render form on page - that's produces status 200, not 302. Also, it's not obvious why you want to send redirect status in case of invalid form.

If this endpoint only used for POST request, then you need display [form errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages) in your template. Or, if you think redirect is a better option in your case, if `is_valid()` returns false just perform [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

Comment: actually it produces status 302, so the first test is fine but it doesn't produce a db object so the second test fail (self.assertEqual(self.query.last().title, "testpost2")

Comment: from code you provided it should not produce the redirect unless `reverse('posts:create')` produces url without ending slash and Django makes auto-redirect to correct route. Try to check if form is actually valid during tests by adding `else` condition after `is_valid()` check with raising error.

Comment: I tested for both the redirect and test validity and are fine. My urls app_name='posts' so redirects fine.

Comment: and if you replace your second tests query with direct `Post.objects.last().title` does it works?

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Comment: wait, did you actually [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) the form (I see you save changes on user)?

Comment: yeah,  obj.save() saves the form, the form works fine I can create objects with it

Comment: No, I mean you set `commit=False` so `Post` will not be save, only user object.